# How to prevent the first row of a table with two dropdown from dynamically change the value of second dropdown when changed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a table which creates dynamically rows with two drop down lists. One for **Subject** and the next is for **Topics**. 
   When a subject value is selected from first row of dropdown list of the table it will populate the topic drop down with appropriate topics name and ID in the second dropdown list in the same row through ajax call from database with laravel

```js
 $('.addRow').on('click' ,function () {
                    addRow();
                });

                function addRow() {

                    var  tr =
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-control subject_selected" name="subject[]" id="subject">' +
                        '<option value=" ">--Select Subject-----</option>' +
                        "@foreach($subject_list as $subject)" +
                        "<option value='{{ $subject-> id }}'>{{ $subject -> SubjectName }}</option>" +
                        "@endforeach"+
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-control topic_selected" name="topic[]" id="topic">' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" id="Amount"/>'+
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-danger remove">X</a>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('tbody').append(tr);

                }
                
                                $(document).on('change','.subject_selected' ,function () {
                    var SubjectID = $(this).val();

                    if(SubjectID){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{ url('/topics') }}" + '/' + SubjectID,
                            typee: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {

                                $('.topic_selected').empty();
                                $.each(data,function (key , value) {
                                     console.log("Key" + key ,"Value" + value);
                                    $('.topic_selected').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value+ '</option>');
                                });

                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log(data)
                            }
                        })
                    }else {
                        $('.topic_selected').empty();
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_tuition_fee">
                                                    <thead>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="topic">Topic</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="Amount">Amount</label></td>
                                                             <td><a class="bg-light btn btn-info addRow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                     <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control subject_selected" name="subject[]" id="subject">
                                                                     <option value=" ">---Select Subject---</option>
                                                                     @foreach($subject_list as  $subject)
                                                                         <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->SubjectName }}</option>
                                                                     @endforeach
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control topic_selected" name="topic[]" id="topic">
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" id="Amount"/>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-danger remove">X</a>
                                                             </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                   <tfoot>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="add_student">SEND</button></td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </tfoot>
                                               </table
```

[image: After Selecting Second dropdown list it will appear with Both Physics topics].
  But the problem arises when a new row is added,then here i will have two rows with four the same dropdown,but when i tried to change subject name from the second row it results into change of both topic row i.e in first row and the second one and so on. 
   So how will i achieve it? I want each row to depend itself i.e when i select a subject from second row must not change with the one in first row.

Comment: Any one with a help..it took me almost a day without solution

Comment: What's needed here is a dynamic ID to distinguish between targeted topics lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a common unique identifier matching each lists of (subject/topics).
Then select the unique targeted list using that identifier. Here I'm using the attribute "data-uid"

I'm reusing your "snippet" to solve it ! But still nobody can execute such code here :)
To see it in action, you can visit the jSfiddle link at the bottom here.

```js
var counter=0;
$('.addRow').on('click' ,function () {
                    addRow();
                });

                function addRow() {

                    var  tr =
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-control subject_selected" name="subject[]" id="subject" data-uid="'+(counter+1)+'">' +
                        '<option value=" ">--Select Subject-----</option>' +
                        "@foreach($subject_list as $subject)" +
                        "<option value='{{ $subject-> id }}'>{{ $subject -> SubjectName }}</option>" +
                        "@endforeach"+
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<select class="form-control topic_selected" name="topic[]" id="topic" data-uid="'+(counter+1)+'">' +
                        '</select>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" id="Amount"/>'+
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-danger remove">X</a>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                    $('tbody').append(tr);
counter++;
                }
                
                                $(document).on('change','.subject_selected' ,function () {
                    var SubjectID = $(this).val();
var targ=$(this).data('uid');
                    if(SubjectID){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{ url('/topics') }}" + '/' + SubjectID,
                            typee: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {

                    
                    
$('.topic_selected[data-uid="' + targ + '"]').empty();
$.each(data,function (key , value) {
console.log("Key" + key ,"Value" + value);
$('.topic_selected[data-uid="' + targ + '"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value+ '</option>');
           });

                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log(data)
                            }
                        })
                    }else {
                        $('.topic_selected').empty();
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_tuition_fee">
                                                    <thead>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="topic">Topic</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="Amount">Amount</label></td>
                                                             <td><a class="bg-light btn btn-info addRow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                     <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control subject_selected" name="subject[]" id="subject"  data-uid="0">
                                                                     <option value=" ">---Select Subject---</option>
                                                                     @foreach($subject_list as  $subject)
                                                                         <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->SubjectName }}</option>
                                                                     @endforeach
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control topic_selected" name="topic[]" id="topic"  data-uid="0">
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" id="Amount"/>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-danger remove">X</a>
                                                             </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                   <tfoot>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="add_student">SEND</button></td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </tfoot>
                                               </table
```

In this fiddle, I'm using an array to replace Ajax data response : https://jsfiddle.net/f4ao1rwq/
You will notice the changes that should be added to your code to work properly.

Comment: Let me check on it

Comment: i failed to populate topics on selected subject through those codes

Comment: The problem is when i tried to show targ on console it give me undefined result..

Comment: The problen is data-uid is not availble..it give out an error undefined on console..am using jquery 3.4.1 with bootstrap 4

Comment: What i did is to declare and initialize the targ variable at the global before success response...Thank you

Comment: Yes Sorry I will update the answer... That was because I can't execute it so I solved it in the fiddle and copied those lines in your code... Glad it helped :)

Comment: Don't worry... But i got the problem during inserting topic and subjects names to database ..the only thing i got from value attribute is an index value of a specific selected value but not respective topics and subject name? What could be a problem?

Comment: Your initial code uses Key as a Value and you need to add the counter as an index to the  name attribute ;) But still  The best way to structure data dynamically added by jQuery is using Json... Later jsonDecode and insert in the Database. I can make you a fiddle for that later...

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing how to make a json out of those dynamic rows : https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/8bhvj0qL/32/ and this is a Pastebin to explain the server side treatment : https://pastebin.com/vvwsiw7F

Comment: I didnt get the point... what i want to do is to get their respectivr names and their actual ID as from DB ...but on your fiddle i failed to understand it

Comment: Because I can't run php and connect to DB in my fiddle, I'm using the same Subject* as value and content. But the jQuery .val() should give you the Id in your case. You can replace by .text() or add the missing one and send them both.